# VBA - Cell interior color based on cell value - compile error - Object required

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to implement below code into one of modules, but it comes with "Object required" error pointing at (Set NegValue = "FALSE") Not sure what is wrong.
I have columns "I" & "M" populated with values "TRUE", "FALSE", "#N/A" from row 3 down. Depense on exports i am using to compare them, amount of row might change.
I need this code to change cell interior color based on cell values up to last row.
What i am doing wrong?

```
Dim PosValue As Variant, NegValue As Variant, NoValue As Variant
Dim Cell2 As Range, TempRange As Range
Dim lr As Long, r As Long, Count As Long, sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set NegValue = "FALSE"
Set PosValue = "TRUE"
Set NoValue = "#N/A"
Set TempRange = Range("I:M")

Set lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Count = 3 To lr

For Each Cell2 In TempRange
If Cell2.Value = PosValue Then _
Cell2.Interior.Color = vbGreen
If Cell2.Value = NegValue Then _
Cell2.Interior.Color = vbRed
If Cell2.Value = NoValue Then _
Cell2.Interior.Color = vbBlue
Next Cell2
Next Count
```

So after changes code will look like below. But still comes with an error. This time error 13.

```
Dim PosValue As String, NegValue As String, NoValue As String
Dim Cell2 As Range, TempRange As Range
Dim lr As Long, r As Long, Count As Long, sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set TempRange = Range("I:M")
NegValue = "FALSE"
PosValue = "TRUE"
NoValue = "#N/A"

lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Count = 3 To lr

For Each Cell2 In TempRange
If Cell2.Value = PosValue Then _
Cell2.Interior.Color = vbGreen
If Cell2.Value = NegValue Then _
Cell2.Interior.Color = vbRed
If Cell2.Value = NoValue Then _
Cell2.Interior.Color = vbBlue
Next Cell2
Next Count
```

Comment: You only use `Set` for object variables such as ranges, not numbers or strings.

Comment: Just delete the 'Set' word, please... And declare the variables between double quotes `As String`.

Comment: Gents, thank you for quick response. So i did what You guys saying but still come with an error. This time error 13 - Mismatch - pointing (If Cell2.Value = PosValue Then)

Comment: What is the value of `Cell2.Value`? Is it a string `"TRUE"`? or is is a value of `True`? They are not the same thing. When it stops, click debug and hover your mouse over the word `Value` to see what it is.

Comment: Do you have errors in any cells? Btw I doubt you really want to loop through several million cells.

Comment: @braX it shows error 2042

Comment: @SJR no i dont. I want this code to check only columns "I" & "M" down to last row. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: 2042 means the value of the cell is in an ERROR `#N/A` state. That needs to be fixed, or checked for an error too...

Comment: Attend to the error first by addressing the comments and answer. But note that each column has a million cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) As SJR stated in the comment, the keyword `Set` is used only to assign objects (object references, to be precise). Simple values like string, boolean or Dates are assigned just with `=`.

```
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet ' Here, we assign a reference to a worksheet.
NegValue = "FALSE" ' This is a simple assignment, Set is not needed (and not allowed)
```

(2) You need to be careful with your data types. You probably have the boolean values `True` and `False` in your cells, not the strings. In that case, you shoudn't compare the content of the cell with strings like `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"` - instead write something like

```
If Cell2.Value = True Then
    Cell2.Interior.Color = vbGreen
else 
    Cell2.Interior.Color = vbRed
end if
```

BTW: Personally, When checking a boolean value, I prefer

```
If Cell2.Value Then
```

resp.

```
If Not Cell2.Value Then
```

(3) Now comes the tricky part. You want to check for "#N/A". This is what Excel displays when the result of a `VLookup` is not found. Be aware: The content of the cell is not the string "#N/A", it is a special error value, "#N/A" is only the way Excel displays this. Best way to check if a cell contains an error is using the function `IsError`.

Your code could look like

```
For Each Cell2 In TempRange
    if isError(Cell2.Value) Then
        Cell2.Interior.Color = vbBlue
    ElseIf cell2.Value Then
        Cell2.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Else
        Cell2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End if
Next cell
```

(4) Instead of using VBA code to color your cells, you should think about using *Conditional Formatting*

Comment: Gents. All of your tips has been helpful. I manage to practice followed by yours tips and got what I  wanted. Thank you all very much